# What is the pattern of the Stirling series?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

It can be shown that:

\begin{eqnarray*}
   n! =  \left ( \frac{n}{e} \right )^n \sqrt{2 \pi n} e^{
     \frac{B_2}{2n} + \frac{B_4}{4 \cdot 3 \cdot n^3} + 
    \cdots
    + \frac{B_{2m}}{2 m ( 2m-1) n^{2 m -1}} + 
    \mathcal{O} \left ( {\frac{1}{n^{2m}}} \right ) },
 \end{eqnarray*}

where $B_i$ stands for the $i$-th Bernoulli number.

We can expand the exponential function $e^z=1+z+z^2/2! + \cdots $
and get something like:

\begin{eqnarray*}
   n! = \left ( \frac{n}{e} \right )^n \sqrt{2 \pi n}
   \left [ 1 + \frac{B_2}{2n} + \frac{B_2^2}{8 n^2}
   + \frac{1}{n^3} \left (
   \frac{B_2^3}{3!  \cdot 2^2} + \frac{B_4}{3!} 
   \right ) + \cdots
 \right ] 
 \end{eqnarray*}

I would like to know the pattern here. It is hard to get after $1/n^3$.

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%3FStirling%20series)  provides the following expansion up to $1/z^{9}$ of the
Gamma function ( $\Gamma (n+1)=n!$).

\begin{eqnarray*}
\Gamma (z)&\propto& 
\frac{ z^{z-1/2}}{e^z} \sqrt{2 \pi} \left (
1 + \frac{1}{12 z} + \frac{1}{288 z^2}-\frac{139}{51840 \, z^3}
-\frac{571}{2488320 \, z^4} +\frac{163879}{209018880 \, z^5}- 
 \frac{5246819}{75246796800 \, z^6}
\right . \\
&-& \frac{534703531}{902961561600 \, z^7}
-\frac{4483131259}{86684309913600 \, z^8}
+\frac{432261921612371}{514904800886784000 \, z^9}
+ \left(O\left(\frac{1}{z^{10}}\right) \right )
 \end{eqnarray*}.

Somewhere, I read that the pattern for the signs inside the brackets is
$+ (++)(--)(++) \cdots $

How can I show this?
Is there a pattern in terms of Bernoulli numbers, so that we can write
something like $n!= A \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} f(B_i) \frac{1}{n^i}$.
What would $f(B_i)$ be?

Thanks for any hint.

**Update**
I found the following 
[article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.2907.pdf)  which discusses my question. However Gerg\"{o} Nemes uses Stirling numbers of second kind, instead of Bernoulli numbers as I did.
Please note the following paragraph on Nemes' text:

*It was pointed out by Paris and Kaminski [6] that “There is no known
closed-form representation for the Stirling coefficients”.*

Comment: You should change in your title "pattern" into "sign pattern"

Comment: No just the sign pattern. I want to know the pattern in terms of Bernoulli numbers, Thanks.

Comment: Then it is a desparate task...  It is like an infinite number of "universal" constants like $\pi$ or $e$... The only property binding them is diverse recurrence relationships

Comment: The $m$-th term of the exponential is $B_{2m}/((2m)(2m-1)(n^{2m-1})$. This means $z^m$ (and $z$ is the number above)  is easy and deterministic. The hard part is to collect equal powers on $1/n$. This is do-able. I will think on this later and if nobody comes up with an answer I might post my own answer.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo The sign pattern follows from formulae (2.3), (2.4) and Lemma 2.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.0166 See formula (1.1) for the notation. You can also find some interesting formulae for these coefficients in https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.5222

Answer (score 1):

We know.
\begin{eqnarray*}
   n! =  \left ( \frac{n}{e} \right )^n \sqrt{2 \pi n} 
   e^{ \frac{B_2}{2n} + \frac{B_4}{4 \cdot 3 \cdot n^3} + 
    \cdots
    + \frac{B_{2m}}{ 2 m ( 2m-1) n^{2 m -1}} + 
    \mathcal{O} \left ( {\frac{1}{n^{2m}}} \right ) },
 \end{eqnarray*}

The expression for the exponential is written as

\begin{eqnarray*}
   e^{ \frac{B_2}{2n} + \frac{B_4}{4 \cdot 3 \cdot n^3} + 
 \cdots
 + \frac{B_{2m}}{2 m ( 2m-1) n^{2 m -1}}} 
    = \prod_i e^{z_i} .
 \end{eqnarray*}

Given that $e^z = 1 + z + z^2/2! + \cdots z^m/m! + \cdots$
 we want to expand
\begin{eqnarray*}
  && \left ( 1 + z_1 t + \frac{z_1^2 t^2}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{z_1^i t^i}{i!} + \cdots 
  \right )  
  \left ( 1 + z_2 t^3 + \frac{z_2^2 t^6}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{z_2^i t^{3i}}{i!} + \cdots
   \right)  \nonumber \\
   && \cdots  
   \left ( 1 + z_j t^{2j-1} + \frac{z_j^2 t^{4j-2}}{2!} + \cdots + 
   \frac{z_j^i t^{i(2j-1)}}{i!} +
  \cdots  \right ) \cdots,
  \quad \quad (1) 
\end{eqnarray*}
where

\begin{eqnarray*}
  1=z_0 \quad , \quad t = \frac{1}{n}
  \quad , \quad z_i=  \frac{B_{2i}}{2i(2i-1)} \quad , i\ge 1, 
\end{eqnarray*}
We are interested on the total $t^j$ power of the product 
above. Let us call $a_i$ the coefficient of $t^i$ in the multiplication.

The constant $t^0$ comes from the independent term which is $1$. That is $a_0=1$.
The $t^1$ term can come only from the first factor, and the constant on other factors.
That is,

\begin{eqnarray*}
  a_1 = z_1 =  \frac{B_2}{2}= \frac{1}{12}.
\end{eqnarray*}
The second power $t^2$ could come only from the first factor.
 That is

\begin{eqnarray*}
  a_2 = \frac{z_1^2}{2!} = \frac{B_2^2}{2!(2^2)} = \frac{B_2^2}{8} = \frac{1}{288}.
\end{eqnarray*}

The third power $t^3$ comes from the first two factors in two ways.
The first factor with a $1$ and the second with $z_2$, or the first
factor with a $z_1^3/3!$, and the second with $1$. That is,

\begin{eqnarray*}
  a_3 = \frac{z_1^3}{3!} + z_2 = \frac{B_2^3}{3! 2^3} + \frac{B_4}{4 \cdot 3}
  = \frac{B_2}{48}  + \frac{B_4}{12} = \frac{B_2^3 + 4 B_4}{48}
  = -\frac{139}{51840}
\end{eqnarray*}

We now look for higher powers of $t=1/n$.  All powers of $t$ have a coefficient
since the first factor indicates this.

Let us consider an arbitrary power $t^k$ $k \ge 3$. 
We look first on the first factor and find all terms that contribute to the $k$-th
power of $t$.

Now how big is $k$ indicates how many factors on the factorization (1) are 
included. For example:

\begin{eqnarray*}
  &&\text{if }  k=0 \quad  \text{all factors} \\
  &&\text{if } \quad 1 \le k < 3 \quad \text{only the first factor} \\
  &&\text{if } \quad 3 \le k < 5 \quad \text{first two factors} \\
  &&\text{if } \quad 5 \le k < 7 \quad \text{first three factors} \\
  && \vdots \\
  &&\text{if } \quad 2 m-1 \le k < 2m+1 \quad \text{first $m$ factors} 
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence we need to evaluate only

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \prod_{i=1}^m \left ( 1 + z_i t^{2i-1} + \frac{z_i^2 t^{4i-2}}{2!} + \cdots + 
   \frac{z_i^j t^{j(2i-1)}}{j!}  \right ). 
\end{eqnarray*}
We want to find the coefficient of the $k$-th power $t^k$, which we name $a_k$.

Let us think that each term of this coefficient has a product of
$k$ terms on the factor above. Some of those terms could correspond to $t^0$, ($i=0$).
We need then to choose of all indices $i=0 \cdots k$ such that
the total power $\sum j (2 i-1))=k$, where $j=0 \cdots k$, and
$i_j=1 \cdots k$.
All possible solutions of this Diophantine equations should be chosen.
Note that we require the presence of each factor, even it it is a $1$.
We can write $a_k$ as

\begin{eqnarray*}
  a_k t^k =  \sum_{\quad \quad \sum  j (2 i-1)=k}
  \; \;
  \prod_i \frac{z_{i}^{j} t^{j(2 i-1)}}{j!}
\end{eqnarray*}
or, replacing  for the $z_i$ symbols

\begin{eqnarray*}
  a_k t^k =  \sum_{\quad \quad \sum  j (2 i-1)=k}
  \; \;
  \prod_i \frac{1}{j!}
  \left ( \frac{B_{2i}}{2i(2i-1)}  \right)^{j} t^{j(2i-1)}.
\end{eqnarray*}

We will verify this formula by computing the next coefficient $a_4$.
Here $k=4$. The solutions that fit $\sum j (2 i-1)=4$,
for $i=1,2$, and $j=0, \cdots 4$ are

\begin{eqnarray*}
    && i=1 \; , \; j=4 \quad ; \quad i=2 \; , \; j=0  \\
    &&  i=1 \; ,\;  j=1  \quad ; \quad i=2 \; , \; j=1
\end{eqnarray*}
We verify that $4 (2-1) + 0 =4$ where in this case the product has only one factor, and
$1(2-1) + 1(4-1)=4$, where the product has two factors.  With this we evaluate 
$a_k$ as follows

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \frac{\left ( \frac{B_2}{2} \right )^4}{4!} + 
  \left ( \frac{B_2}{2} \right )
  \left ( \frac{B_4}{4 \times 3} \right ) = -\frac{571}{2488320},
\end{eqnarray*}

This last computation could be verified by using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(%20(Bernoulli(2)%2F2)%5E4)%2F4!%20%2B%20((Bernoulli(4)%2F(4*3)))%20%20%20*%20(Bernoulli(2)%2F2))

The sign pattern is still an open question that might be solved with
the explicit formula above. A simplification of this formula
would be an interesting exercise.